# Android ActionBarCompat library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar-compat

I'm having trouble using ActionBarCompat support library which was released yesterday. I have updated support repository and included path to appcompat-v7 repository in build.gradle as Chris Banes pointing out in DevBytes - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc .

```
dependencies {
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+')
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+')}
```

Build goes well and I can use classes such as ActionBarActivity from this library but I cannot use styles and any resources so I cannot use following themes - @style/Theme.AppCompat etc. I was thinking that I'll find source files in .../sdk/extras/android/.../"supportrepo" so I would reference it like ActionBarSherlock by gradle but that didn't seems to be the correct answer.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Actually I found these resources in sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat folder. But they didn't seem to be referenced in support repository.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem. There is this documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

If you look at the part that says "Adding library with resources", it says this: "Add the support library feature project identifier to the dependencies section. For example, to include the appcompat project add compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+" to the dependencies section, as shown in the following example:" 

That's exactly what I did (And looks as though you did as well). So, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Android Studio and I have the same res-resolving issue in the my `values/styles.xml`.

It says it cannot resolve `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light`, but at compile-time *(gradle)* and runtime everything works fine *(Android 2.3.3 & 4.3)*.

I'd like to get rid of the warning that the res cannot be resolved.

<strike>**How can I tell Android Studio that this res can be found in the appcompat-v7 repo?**</strike>
*(This question was related to a bug in Android Studio that has already been fixed.)*

---

Below you see what I did. I hope this will help. Suggestions appreciated.
*The source for the appcompat library can found on [github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v7/appcompat).*

#### Gradle integration:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group:'com.android.support', name:'appcompat-v7', version:'18.0.+'
    ...
}
```

#### Style-files:

values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Custom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Custom" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_custom</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome|showCustom</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

values-v14/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Custom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Custom" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_custom</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome|showCustom</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity *(only the extend is mandatory)*:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Views.inject(this);

        setupNavigationDrawer();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml *(setting android:theme is mandatory)*:

```
    <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Where is the trick? Maybe I can't see but it seems to me like normal setup. Thank you.

Comment: There is no trick. You don't need a trick. I posted this so you might find a mistake you made.

Comment: Great response. Solved Theme.AppCompat not resolved issues. +1

Comment: Is the part in bold at the top a separate question you are asking, or is it a heading, where the part after the break is the solution?

Comment: It was a seperate question, which was related to a bug in Android Studio that has already been fixed.  
~~ I updated by post.

Answer (score 7):

There is a known bug (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56312) where the Android Studio IDE will flag the style as red (that bug is for ActionBarSherlock, but the issue is to do with an aar containing styles and the sources for that aar not being visible to Android Studio).

Specifically, comment #8 (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56312#c4) shows the observed behaviour, and comment #10 (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56312#c10) notes that the layout editor is fixed, but the code editor is not.

Thus, the program should build & run fine, just show the style in red when viewed in the XML style editor.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer to [my reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17860418/1004634).

Comment: Android Studio 0.2.7 has been released. This version should fix this bug. http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio027released

Comment: Bug seems to still be present in `0.4.4`.  Style works, but flags as red.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried Gradle yet so I am not sure but it seems you also need to copy resources into your project.It contains Theme.AppCompat.

I got success in Eclipse by following below steps.

Import `android-support-v7-appcompat` as a libray project from below path.(you might have saved sdk on different path)

> D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\android\support\v7

The I just added this library into my project and things worked out of box.

Comment: Yes, we post it at the same moment. :) So it isn't as simple as adding one line into build.gradle file like was told in video...

Comment: @Michal I am still newbie in Gradle.Since it is library project you can follow same steps as you do while importing other library projects.

Comment: Thank you, Vipul. This is the way you can do it. In android studio you import existing module into project, setup Gradle files accordingly and its good to go. But that does not differ from importing ActionBarSherlock or any other module a bit so I am a little disappointed.

Comment: That does not work for me here for unknown reason in Eclipse. v7-appcompat is imported as a library and set up as written in google dev docs. When referencing the library, I get an error and its contents are not available in my project. Don't know what to try more...

Answer (score 2):

I also added the same 2 lines to my dependencies section in the build.gradle file. Compiling started to work but I got runtime errors. Then I discovered the option **Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files**. This seemed to do the trick. (I'm on Android Studio 0.2.9)

Comment: I had all dependencies declared in Gradle and this resolved the "red" Android Studio was presenting. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Lastest Studio 0.8.1

Create new project and set Style to AppTheme. then crash.

My solution:

File -> Project Structure -> Dependicies -> + (plus) ->  select appcompact, support, ....

And error fixed.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cf https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/ef5LyGyMddy

**David Van de Ven**

> Except someone forgot to update the support repository, so anyone
>   using android studio will have their gradle builds break when trying
>   to use the new support library.

**Roman Nurik**

> +David Van de Ven we're working on that.

Comment: So there's the problem. :)